# How to determine who delete a heap object

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, heap-memory, heap-corruption

Our software application randomly crashed on a customer's system. The bad thing is that we could not reproduce the crashes on our side. The customer sent us log files and dump files, by analyzing which we believe the crashes were caused by premature deletion of certain heap objects. But we could not locate where these heap objects were deleted. My question is if there is a way to determine which function delete a heap object. Since we may need to run it on the customer's system, the solution should not deteriorate efficiency too much.

The application is written in native C++ and runs in Windows 7. The heap objects were wrapped in smart pointers and were created and used by multiple threads.

Comment: I wonder how you ended up with a premature deletion if you are using smart pointers?  (the first thing I would do, if you haven't done it already, is grep all your source code for the keyword `delete`, and make sure nobody is Doing It Wrong (tm).  i.e. in an application that uses smart pointers the `delete` keyword should never appear anywhere)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We need more information to help you.

Comment: Note that you can get similar crashes without premature deletes if somewhere in your codebase someone/something is writing to invalid/unallocated memory addresses and manages to overwrite some of the heap's metadata, corrupting the heap.  valgrind is often your friend in tracking down that sort of damage...

Comment: I'd like to add something to @JeremyFriesner have said. It is possible that a thread writes to an object after the owner thread has released that object.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner The destructors of those classes are all protected.

Comment: @user3552888 I'm a little confused; if you are convinced that the compiler will prevent delete from being called, then what is it that makes you suspect that the problem is caused by a premature delete?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Perhaps because marking a destructor `protected` doesn't "prevent delete from being called"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit in that case, I'm confused about why protected destructors are relevant to the discussion :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Yes me too

Answer (score 0):

> My question is if there is a way to determine which function delete a heap object.

Are you not the team that wrote the application? You should know which functions do what, and if you don't then read the documentation, and if there isn't any then read the code.

Now that the formalities are out of the way, I do sympathise. Occurrences like these can be a real pain to diagnose, particularly given the sensitivities of potentially requiring reproduction on a customer system. Your first step will be to load the dump files into your debugger and thoroughly inspect the state of the system. Your best devs will need to be on the lookout for unexpected clues that trigger "eureka" moments in their lizard brains, that point them to some unexpected system state that they nonetheless recognise as being remotely possible. If that doesn't happen you're SOL tbh.

Jeremy also gives some good ideas above. It's by no means guaranteed that running valgrind now will reveal the problem, but if there *is* a systemic problem in your codebase then doing a thorough test run over valgrind could potentially reveal it. With luck and human heuristics you may be able to determine with confidence that the problem is what caused the customer's crash. But... you're already doing valgrind testing as part of your release checks, right...?

What else... hmmm... well you ask about tracing. You can't just flip a switch to get what you want - you'd have to create then activate some highly verbose debugging mode in your application, which is necessarily going to impact performance, and if the problem is as rare/unexpected as it sounds, you may have to run this thing for months. Probably not wildly viable.

Finally, just to cover all your bases, run your code through a static analyzer (again, that's if you're not already) to check for *really* obvious errors. Don't expect much from this but it can sometimes lead to a quick win when someone's been writing code hungover. CppCheck has its moments (though it can also be a bit of a dingleberry if I'm being honest).

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not one of the programmers who designed and implemented this application. This is a quite complicated application for manufacturing automation. Reviewing the code didn't help me a lot. I did static code analysis and found some problems. After we fixed these problems, the application seemed more stable, but still crashed.

Comment: @user3552888: Are those programmers still employed in your business?